# Can we swtich to English language in German Visual Studio 2012 on German Windows 8 with German .net Framwork?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio 2012 in German on Windows8 with German language and .Netframework 4 with German language. I want to change at least the IDE language of Visual Studio to English, Is it possible? How?

Since I don't have admin right to install anything on work computer, I can't try out probable solution.

I would appreciate your suggestions, Since I find it difficult to debug and understand error messages in German.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Language Interface Packs (LIPs) and Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246590.aspx) should cover everything you need to know. The relevant part can be found in the section on *Changing the Language Used for the UI Text in Visual Studio*.
You should note however that the language packs seem to require at least a Professional license, it doesn't work with VS2012 Express.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the link does not always change the language package. It's a problem of Microsoft developers. If you want to get Visual Studio in english, please check the package language you are installing when you open the .exe file. Check that it says "ENU".

This is the correct link to Visual Studio 2015:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48157

Sometime you switch language but it download the same file, and just when you open it, you see the same language being installed, and you are thinking that you selected the corrected language, and you did, but microsoft did you gave you the right file, and only when you see in the installation title, you can know that you are installing the correct language.

[image]